# REGEXP smart extra-letter detection

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I am working on a regular expression to match words even if the user input has some extra or changed letters. For example if the user input is `pgone` my regexp should still match `phone` or if the user input is `phini` it should also match `phone`. I have no idea how to do this.

I have tried the following but it matches me some extra words:

`[[:<:]](p|)[a-zA-Z]{0,2}(g|)[a-zA-Z]{0,2}(o|)[a-zA-Z]{0,2}(n|)[a-zA-Z]{0,2}(e|)[a-zA-Z]{0,}[[:>:]]`.

Comment: This is better done with a mapping with acceptable misspellings mapped to the 'right' word or a metric that maps an edit distance to the target word. The regex approach will rapidly grow unmanageable for your goal.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is define the exact mistakes you expect the user to do using atomic groups:

```
^(?>phone|phine|pgone|phoni|ghone.|p?one|p.one)$
```

You can add some other words and patterns to match other possible typos but I don't think this should be the way to go here. You probably should calculate Levenshtein distance as suggested by Paul Crovella to check the distance between the string typed in and the correct one.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :*